# How to pass changeset that has a put_assoc in Phoenix Form

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

How to pass a changeset in phoenix form?

Here's a snippet from the controller:

`def new(conn, _params) do
    changeset = Blog.change_post(%Post{})
    render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
  end`

But I get this error
`key :user not found in: %{}`

Here's my post changeset:
`def changeset(post, attrs) do
    post
    |> cast(attrs, [:title, :content, :is_published])
    |> validate_required([:title, :content])
    |> put_slug()
    |> put_assoc(:user, attrs.user)
  end`

Comment: check if `attrs,user` has something, print it with `|> put_assoc(:user, IO.inspect(attrs.user))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that your "attrs" has no key :user and you are trying to access it in the line with "attrs.user".

If I would guess, I would say you should pass the params to the function "change_post" like "Blog.change_post(%Post{}, params)", this way you could pass those params to the creation of the changeset.